# How To Define Specific ReadItem Finder with List View in External List?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, bcs

I have an external list which is using the BCS to pull data from a custom database.  This database has several views which have the same column structure and several that do not.  I have been adding ReadList operations for each view and then creating a new list view to display it.  What i end up with is a single external list which has views based off the database views.

The problem i am having is that i cannot create working list views for any of the ReadList operations which use a different column structure in the database view.  I realize this is because the ReadItem view does not contain the fields which are being displayed.

The error i actually get is:
""cannot be found in ViewGroup associated with SpecificFinder (Read Item) operation"

I am able to create a new ReadItem operation which uses the alternate column structure, but i am unable to figure out how to tell the specific List View to use the new Read Item rather than the other one.  The only way I have gotten this to work is by creating a whole new list.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I would like to only use one list with multiple views, but how can i tell my list views to use a specific read item finder?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to change your ReadItem operation to include all fields that are provided in your various views (ReadList) operations.

To put it simply ReadItem should provide the full set of fields for use in the list.

Comment: Does that mean that the fields that are not present are going to show every time on the ReadItem screen?

Comment: yes, the read item screen should contain all fields